# Image url instead of Base64 - Markdown Editor

Tags: javascript, markdown, wysiwyg

[Toastui wysiwyg/markdown editor](https://nhnent.github.io/tui.editor/) encodes image files into Base64. Well, this seems handy but I expect the DB to be used quite heavily for a long term. This will cause some issues - searching slow, implementing image library.

I have been working to remove this encoding option but no great success yet.
For example, instead of storing images like...

```
![image.JPG](data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAkACQAAD/4RD6RXhpZ)
```

it should be...

```
![Somepath](images/image.jpg)
```

Any documentation? or any examples to refer?

Thanks !

Comment: well, what have you tried so far? personally I would go with a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) but that would require you installing pandoc on the server... so maybe a regex would catch 99.9% of the cases?

Comment: well i am still figuring out, can you please give an example on how it can be done in Pandoc filter.?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a graphic file named **test.jpg** that resides in the same directory as the markdown file:

```
![](test.jpg)
```